# How secure is Java's hashCode()?

Tags: hash, java

On our views in a Java web application, currently I am using `hashCode` as Id's for objects so that at server end I can get the same object back.

However, I am wondering how secure Java's `hashCode` really is so that someone cannot hack it to retrieve other person's objects.  I am not very inclined towards Encryption-Decryption mechanism as it causes much CPU.

What other **fast** yet **secure** mechanisms I can use ?

Comment: Did you benchmark proper crypto hashes or are you simply claiming it's too slow?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `hashCode` will generate unique identifiers. Check the documentation.

Comment: "Is Java `hashCode() secure?" = "Is using a polynomial as a hash function secure?"

Comment: Sorry, but this question is ... very mindboggling. I need a glass of water

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're breaking one of the `hashCode()` taboos; you're using its output as a key identifier. **That's wrong.**

You see, the output of `hashCode()` (in its default implementation) is a 32-bit unsigned integer, that's roughly 4 billion unique hashCodes. Sounds quite a lot? Well, not so much. Applying the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) in this case shows as that with about 77000 objects, you have about 50% chance of collision. 50% chance of two objects having the the same hashCode.

Another issue is that the implementation of `hashCode()` can change from one Java version to the other. It's not meant to be permanent identifier of an object, so there's nothing forcing it to be consistent across versions.

If you insist on using hashes as object identifiers, then it's much better to have your own method instead of `hashCode()` to use for your key identifiers (for example, `getMySpecialHashKey()`. You can uses something like `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")` to digest the object into a nice 256-bit key.

**My recommendation:** Ditch the whole idea of hashing the object and rather generate a random identifier for your object when you construct it. Something along the lines of (in Java)

```
SecureRandom secRand = new SecureRandom();
byte[] objIdBytes = new byte[16]; //128-bit
secRand.nextBytes(objIdBytes);
String objId = Base64.encodeBase64String(objIdBytes); //Here's your ID
```

You also seem to bind access to an object only to knowledge of its key. **That's also wrong.** A proper permission-based model with proper authentication and authorization is needed.

Comment: There's nothing forcing `hashCode()` to be consistent even across different JVM invocations.

Comment: _"If you insist on using hashes as object identifiers"_ **DON'T**.

Comment: Good answer. A graph showing the probability of at least one hash collision in a set of n objects is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

Comment: +1 good answer. It might be more straight forward to use UUID.randomUUID() instead of SecureRandom to generate an ID, however.

Comment: @EricLippert: And that's probably assuming a perfectly random hash function. Hash functions that are optimized for performance are likely to be even worse

Comment: No, not good answer.  Good diagnosis, terrible recommendation.  All random numbers have a chance of collision, even ones generated using crypto-strength algorithms.  Just use an atomic counter.  All that the unpredictable IDs are doing are supporting the attitude that obscurity of the key is providing sufficient security.  It's not, as the final paragraph points out.  And once a proper ACL method is used, randomization of IDs provides no benefit.

Comment: @BenVoigt I suggest you take an introductory crypto course before calling the recommendations of others "terrible".

Comment: @Terry: Try reading more than six words of my comment before going on the offense.  You obviously have no idea what my training is.  I could recommend that you take a proper course on stochastic processes before making claims about the uniqueness of pseudo-random numbers, but instead I'll just **refer to the last sentence of this answer itself for why the recommendation to use a random identifier to control access is wrong**.  Oh wait, I already did.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's perfectly okay to feel this way. Allow me to clear some confusion here first. We have _two_ separate issues: 1- The usage of high probability collision-prone UID generation process. 2- Limiting access rights based on knowledge of the ID. Those are **two** separate and _completely_ different issues. The first one is about the high likelihood of collisions between objects and the inaptness of such identification schema. That issue is handled using CSPRNG that provide extreme unlikelihood of such collisions. The second issue (continued in the next comment)

Comment: @BenVoigt The second issue is permissions and access rights to objects and limiting them to the knowledge of the ID. That issue is handled using well-established and properly planned ACL models. This answer does **not** approach the second issue (except in the last paragraph). The "terribleness" of the recommendation comes from your lack of understanding (please don't take this the wrong way. We all lacked understanding at some point, then we learned better). The recommendation in this answer is strictly about (and I quote from myself) _using hashes as object identifiers_. Nothing more.

Comment: @Adnan: I completely agree with the final paragraph.  The suggestion of random IDs contradicts it, however.  (Add to that the order in which they are presented, and a questioner looking for a quick fix is probably going to fixate on `SecureRandom`).  The second issue *changes* the first, because it makes unpredictability of little importance... and then for performance reasons one ought to avoid a CSPRNG, since it is expensive to compute and makes lookup inefficient.

Comment: I suppose that there might still be some argument for adding randomness, such as not disclosing the number of entries in the database (or related: the rate they are generated).  But with respect to the first issue -- generating identifiers which don't collide, a CSPRNG is inferior.  The identifier needs to be unique, it does not need to be random.

Comment: A final short summary point: the rate of collisions in randomly generated IDs is controlled by the size of the IDs, and whether a CSPRNG is used makes no difference at all.

Comment: @Adnan Certainly no crypto expert (and a 256bit key makes the chances of a collision minimal to say the least - works fine for git), but I agree with Ben here: If you don't use the object's hash/key/whatever for authorization, why not just use a simple counter? Guaranteed to be collision free, faster and simpler - also predictable but assuming a correct authentication method that's not harmful.

Comment: Minor implementation note: to generate a 128-bit secure random ID in java, simply use [`UUID.randomUUID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29).

Comment: @Voo a counter is only unique to a single process. If you have multiple servers, or just multiple processes creating these ID's, it becomes a real pain trying to co-ordinate them to implement a counter. A random number from a sufficiently large space quickly becomes _much_ simpler.

Answer (score 31):

Java `hashCode()` was never intended to be used like this. Don't do ever it! It is even legal (while not recommended) for all instances of a class to return the same hashCode. The contract in Java is "two objects that are considered equal must have same hashcode". No more, no less. It would for example be valid to return hashcode 1 for all uneven numbers and 0 for even ones.

`hashCode` is used for faster lookup in Collections such as `HashMap` and collisions are *expected*.

Many classes define their own version of `hashCode()`, and if you know the code, you can often easily tell or guess the hashcode.

So, this is absolutely insecure.

Comment: The way I like to look at it, the purpose of hash codes is to speed up some (hopefully most) comparisons between things that are different, since anything whose hashcode doesn't equal X's hashcode can be regarded as unequal to X without even having to look at it.  Not all classes can implement their hashcode in a way that allows any speed-up, but hashcode exists to allow those which can implement it usefully to do so.

Answer (score 12):

It is not cryptographically secure, because that's not part of its requirements.

How the hashCode is implemented is an implementation detail up to the JVM and can be different for different object types (objects can override the hashCode method and provide an own implementation).

The purpose of the Java hashCode is to identify objects when placing them in hash tables. Its main requirement is performance. It also has a length of just 32bit, which is too short to avoid collisions. For its intended purpose (hash tables) two objects having the same hash is only a minor problem, but to identify objects without ambiguity collisions are a big problem.

But you should generally not allow any user to access any object just because they know the objects hash-code. Use a proper rights management scheme. Use password-protected user accounts where each user has a different set of permission-parameters. When the user tries to access an object, check if its permissions allow them to do so and reject the request when they don't.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly isn't secure enough for a situation where guessing values can reveal information.

At least some of the overrides aren't even secure enough to use as a hash-code in the face of arbitrary user-selected input (it's really easy to do a hash-DoS attack against anything using Java's `String.hashCode()` override).

In cases where you want an identifier, I recommend taking a simple identifier (e.g. a numeric key in a database, an atomically incremented integer which is a key into a hash table, etc), and then appending a cryptographic hash of that and a salt.

That is, your publicly-exposed ID would be of the form (in language agnostic form):

```
Concatenate(PrivateID, HexString(SHA256(UTF8Bytes(Concatenate(Salt, PrivateID)))))
```

(You could remove part of the hash for a smaller ID at the cost of reduced time to brute-force).

Then the private ID can be obtained as a substring, and the full id can be verified again. The general procedure is also easily ported between languages.

The handful of CPU cycles this will cost isn't going to be a big impact relative to the rest of the system, unless your system is so trivial that you won't be using much CPU anyway, so unless you're running this on something really low-powered (as in, far less powerful than a cheap phone) it won't be a concern.

In cases where you actually want to use a hash-code as a hash-code and have to deal with user-selected input, then use a seedable hash algorithm (e.g. SpookyHash) and base your seed on start-up time (or better still, a mix of start-up time and the time you create the hash container). (Nothing to do with cryptographic hashes, so they can be much faster; the *only* security risk this avoids is hash-DoSing).